# От налоговой инспекции / Из налоговой инспекции?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно построить фразу?

*...получен ответ от (налоговой инспекции)*

или

*...получен ответ из (налоговой инспекции)*

Comment: ... получен ответ из налоговой инспекции по поводу наших поздравлений работников этой службы с Новым годом. Нас благодарят за добрые пожелания и зовут попить чайку на старый новый год... (из дневника секретаря директора ОАО "Великореченский чесночно-чулочный комбинат")

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что правильно ИЗ. Поскольку "получен ответ (откуда? Из чего?) из налоговой инспекции". 
  Если же указываете конкретного человека, писавшего вам ответ, то тогда уже "получен ответ (от кого?) от Иванова И.И.".

Answer (score 1):

Если ответ **от имени** налоговой инспекции как юридического лица, то "от налоговой инспекции".
Если это ответ из какой-то подструктуры, подразделения или от сотрудника, представлять налоговую не уполномоченного (правом первой подписи не обладающего), то уместно "из". 
Впрочем, это не абсолютная рекомендация. Можно еще уровень официальности самого вопроса посмотреть, не думаю, что поздравления с юбилеем тянут на официоз, даже если оно подписано руководителем.

Кстати, заглавная буква в "налоговой инспекции" не нужна, если это только не используется как условное обозначение.

Comment: Букву исправлю, спасибо)

Comment: Я и сам могу.

Comment: Вот это еще, плиз :  
>Если это ответ из какого-то
подструктуры, подразделения или сотрудника

Прям перл))) *Ответ из сотрудника*, хорошо, что не омлет...

Comment: Вы довольны, г-н Бревновглазунезамечающий?

Comment: Если Вы исполните мое третье пожелание, это будет просто праздник какой-то! Можно озвучить?

Comment: Озвучить можно. Выполнить - это уж как себя вести будете.
Если

Comment: *Обоим пожизненный эцих без гвоздей*, вот такое контрольное пожелание...  
![Киндзадза](http://www.vothouse.ru/img/films/20101028/06.jpg)

Comment: Это Ваша фота?

Comment: Присоединяйтесь)